# Extending my Azure DevOps Pipeline to include Build validation for all Pull Requests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 30 or so Java Microservices that run of the same ci and cd template. i.e. Each of my Microservices has a build pipeline as follows and as shown below it runs automatically on a merge to master:

```
name: 0.0.$(Rev:r)

trigger: 
  - master
pr: none 

variables:
- group: MyCompany

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: <id>/yaml-templates

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    - job: build
      displayName: Build
      steps:
      - template: my-templates/ci-build-template.yaml@templates
  - stage: PushToContainerRegistry
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
    - job: PushToContainerRegistry
      displayName: PushToContainerRegistry
      steps:
      - template: my-templates/ci-template.yaml@templates
```

Where ci-build-template.yaml contains...

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    path: s 

  - task: PowerShell@2

  - task: Gradle@2
    displayName: 'Gradle Build'

  - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
    displayName: SonarQube Analysis

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy build/docker to Staging Directory
```

I would like to implement pr build validation wherever someone raises a pr to merge into master. In the PR build only the Build stage should run and from the build template only some tasks within ci-build-template.yaml should run.

A few questions for my learning:

How can i uplift the yaml pipeline above to make the "PushToContainerRegistry" skip if it is a pr build?

How can i uplift ci-build-template.yaml to make the "SonarQubePrepare@4" and "CopyFiles@2" skip if it is a pr build?

And lastly how can i uplift the yaml pipeline above to enable build validation for all pr's that have a target branch of master?

Whilst doing my own research i know you can do this via clickops but I am keep on learning on how to implement via yaml.

thanks

Comment: Check out [official docs samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/templates?view=azure-devops#use-extends-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i uplift the yaml pipeline above to make the
> "PushToContainerRegistry" skip if it is a pr build?
>
> How can i uplift ci-build-template.yaml to make the
> "SonarQubePrepare@4" and "CopyFiles@2" skip if it is a pr build?

Just need to use condition of task:

For example,

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- script: |
   echo Write your commands here
   
   echo Hello world
   
   echo $(Build.Reason)
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

Above definition will skip the step if Pull request trigger the pipeline.

Please refer to these documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#using-the-trigger-type-in-conditions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services

[image]

> And lastly how can i uplift the yaml pipeline above to enable build
> validation for all pr's that have a target branch of master?

You can use this expression in the condition:

`eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')`

If you are based on DevOps git repo, then just need to add branch policy is ok:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#configure-branch-policies

Comment: Thanks. Does the expression you have above go in the path filter for the build policy? Or does it go into the yaml file I had in my original post?

Comment: The expression needs to add to the task that you want to skip in some conditions. Just add to the condition section.